# C# - How to get item from the list with complex type

Tags: c#, list, search

I am new in c# and have a problem with lists.

**I have a class Message:**

```
public class Message
{
    public int MessageId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Autor { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }
}
```

**and class MessageHandler:**

```
class MessageHandler
{
    private List<Message> _dummyMessages = new List<Message>()
       {
            new Message(){
                MessageId = 1,
                CreatedDate = new DateTime(2014, 5, 27),
                Text = "Srpska vodoprivreda...",
                Autor = "Marko Markovic",
                Source = "Twitter"

            },
            new Message(){
                MessageId = 2,
                CreatedDate = new DateTime(2014, 5, 27),
                Text = "Aerodrom Beograd...",
                Autor = "Zoran Zoric",
                Source = "B92"

            }
        };

    public List<Message> GetLatestMessages(int nrMessagesToReturn)
    {
        List<Message> retVal;

        retVal = this._dummyMessages.GetRange(0, nrMessagesToReturn);

        return retVal;
    }

   //todo: Search list _dummyMessages and get Source and
   //check is it equal to "Twitter"
}
```

My problem is that I dont know how to get Source from `List<Message>` :( I started like this:

```
public List<Message> SearchBySource()
{
    List<Message> retVal;

    foreach (Message m in _dummyMessages) 
    {
        //..........
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

but what to do to get Source from Message?

I want to take Source from Message and then check is it "Twitter", because I want to count all "Twitter" sources from my list...

Sorry for stupid question, and thanks for help!!

Comment: Use linq dummyMessages.Where(x=> x.Source=="Twitter").ToList();

Comment: Given the snippets above I don't understand why you need to ask that question. It's about the most basic knowledge (which you actually would appear to have). Furthermore: are you using Visual Studio? Do you know Intellisense? Try it in your `foreach`: m.

Comment: kostas is right, but you can directly call the count method like this: `_dummyMessages.Where(obj => obj.Source == "Twitter").Count();`

Comment: @Koryu: directly is `_dummyMessages.Count(obj => obj.Source == "Twitter")`

Comment: @Tim true. well, so many possibilities :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
List<Message> retVal;

foreach (Message m in _dummyMessages) 
{
    // Check if the message's source is twitter
    if(Message.Source=="Twitter")
            retVal.Add(Message);
}

return retVal;
```

Or using LINQ:

```
return _dummyMessages.Where(x=>x.Source=="Twitter").ToList();
```

Both of the above code samples will go in the body of `SearchBySource()` method.

One suggestion I have to make is you use a parameter, like below:

```
public List<Message> SearchBySource(string source)
{
    return _dummyMessages.Where(x=>x.Source==source).ToList();
}
```

in order your method being more meaningfull. You are seraching by source, so you have to provide the source.

Answer (score 4):

```
 var count = _dummyMessages.Count(m => m.Source == "Twitter");
```

ref: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 2):

`Source` is a public property in your class, that means you can access it directly:

```
public List<Message> SearchBySource(string source)
{
    List<Message> retVal = new List<Message>();
    foreach (Message m in _dummyMessages) 
    {
        if(source == m.Source)
            retVal.Add(m);
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

You can also use `List.Find` with a predicate:

```
List<Message> retVal = _dummyMessages.Find(m => m.Source == source);
```

Another option is to use LINQ to count all messages with source="Twitter":

```
int countTwitter = _dummyMessages.Count(m => m.Source == "Twitter");
```

or to return a list with all messages that have source="Twitter":

```
List<Message> retVal = _dummyMessages.Where(m => m.Source == "Twitter").ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Program
{


     public static List<Message> SearchBySource()
        {
        MessageHandler msg = new MessageHandler();
        List<Message> msgContent = msg.GetLatestMessages(1);
        return msgContent;
        }

     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
      List<Message> mymess =  SearchBySource();
        foreach (Message m in mymess) 
        {
        Console.WriteLine(m.Source);
        }
         Console.ReadLine();
     }
```

Example for the Code to get first entry , returns Twitter.